# jquery :first element of a list of anchor tags

Tags: jquery

My jquery looks like this

```
$('#content a[href*="Something"]')
```

and returns this

```
[<a href="Something1">blah</a>,
 <a href="Something2">blah</a>,
 <a href="Something3">blah</a>,
 <a href="Something4">blah</a>]
```

I'm trying to use `:first` to get the first element.

```
$('#content a[href*="Something"]:first')
```

But it's not working. The `#content` part seems to be causing a problem. How can I fix this without removing `#content`?

Edit: my html

```
<div id="content>
  <a href="Something1">blah</a>
  <a href="Something2">blah</a>
  <a href="Something3">blah</a>
  <a href="Something4">blah</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please give full or detailed HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why `:first` isn't working for you, it works for me in similar situations, but if nothing else works, try using `filter()` instead:

```
$('#content a[href*="Something"]').filter(':first')
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at [this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nUtHg/)

Answer (score -1):

Use [eq selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```
$('a[href*="Something"]:eq(0)')
```

If you want to use the context then try this.

```
var context = $('#content');
var firstElement = $('a[href*="Something"]:eq(0)',context);
```

Comment: elements are 0 indexed, so this should be $('a[href*="Something"]:eq(0)')

Comment: @shortstick: Corrected, however the intention is to use the proper selector.

Comment: :first is as valid a method as :eq(0): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234087/are-jquerys-first-and-eq0-selectors-functionally-equivalent

Comment: @shortstick: I checked with the :first it didn't work, hence the answer.